# What do you call people who are constantly moving [i.e., "in motion"]?

Tags: single-word-requests

*Moving* here does not mean moving to a new city or something like that. I am talking about the people that just can't stay at one place. It is impossible for them to sit put at one place and relax.

Comment: New Yorkers, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Restless*, *bustling*, *fidgety*, *fidgeting*, *antsy* (informal), "in constant nervous motion", "flitting from place to place like a dying bluebottle"(informal), "twitching like a junky in need of a fix" (extremely informal).

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the word "fidgety"?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about a person who's unable to sit still (as opposed to having an irresistible urge to travel), the word we used when I was growing up was **hyper**, short for *hyperactive*.  Nowadays the full name of the diagnosis is *Attention Deficit / Hyperactivity Disorder*, or **ADHD** for short, and I often hear it used as a shorthand term for a person with that diagnosis.

> Why's Johnny so *hyper* today?

or

> Sorry I can't keep Johnny from screaming and running around the restaurant - he's *ADHD*.

Despite having grown up hearing (and sometimes using) *hyper*, I can't really recommend either of these - they're both extremely informal, and can be interpreted as either overindulgent of bad behavior OR dismissive of the victims of a serious condition.  So be forewarned.

Answer (score 2):

***Peripatetic.*** This word could refer to someone who moves or walks about, or who does not stay in one place. I do not believe it implies necessity or compulsion to move.

***Itinerant.*** This word is slightly more broad in definition than *peripatetic.* It refers to someone who moves from place to place. It may be more appropriate, depending on the context.

Comment: +1 for _peripatetic,_ which is exactly the word I was thinking of when I saw the question. (I cleaned up the answer's style and diction a bit – apologies if I changed the meaning at all.)

Answer (score 1):

I might call them "antsy", or say that they have "ants in their pants", though the latter is pretty informal.

Answer (score 0):

Always on the go/agitated/full of nervous agitation/restless/hyper/itchy feet/always up and doing

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for them to sit put at one place and relax?

How about "*hyperactive*" ?

Answer (score 0):

The technical term is ***akathisia*** defined as a state of motor restlessness ranging from an inner restlessness to an inability to sit still.

> [from a-  + -kithisia , ultimately from Greek cathedra  seat]]

For more details see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akathisia)

Answer (score 0):

I'd also call such a person **energizer** or *mike jagger* :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say they are in perpetual motion. In Italian, it's *moto perpetuo*.